# /usr/bin/env php shebang prints headers when called via sudo or cron

Tags: php

I am using `#!/usr/bin/env php` to invoke a PHP script at the command line, which has been working great. PHP correctly detects the command line and suppresses HTTP headers.

But I started calling my script via `sudo` or via a cron job, it has started print HTTP headers.

```
>> ./test 
Hello world!

>> sudo -u nathan ./test 
Content-type: text/html

Hello world!
```

./test just contains the following code:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

echo 'Hello world!' , "\n";
```

I think this has something to do with whether the script is passed a tty, but I am unsure. Is there a way to prevent these headers from being printed? I can't use the "-q" argument, I don't think, since I am calling it via env.

Comment: What are the contents of `./test`?

Comment: "I can't use the `-q` argument, I don't think" Don't think, *do*. There's no reason you can't use `-q` in there, but I don't know why you're using `env` at all since you don't appear to be modifying any environment variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script prints HTTP headers because `/usr/bin/env php` calls the CGI version of the PHP executable instead of CLI. You can verify this by running `which php` first to find out where `/usr/bin/env php` points to. Then run `/usr/bin/php -v` (or whatever path `which php` returns) to see if it is CGI or CLI.

By default, PHP is built as both CLI and CGI. So either fix your PHP setup, or use hardcoded path with the `-q` option instead of `env`, because you are right, you can't use options with `env`. I would do the first.

Comment: Thank you so much. It turns out that **sudo env** has a different set of paths defined then just **env**, and as a result, was calling the CGI version.